# Cannot Play Audio in React Typescript with play() function | Error: Property 'play' does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, audio, jsx

I have created a simple Audio Player in React js with Typescript and I am trying to use the normal HTML5 functions to Play and Pause the Audio but it is not working.

When I do `mytrack.play();` I  get this error: `Property 'play' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./SimplePlayer.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

export interface SimplePlayerProps {}

var mytrack = document.getElementById("mytrack");
console.log(mytrack);
mytrack.play();

export class SimplePlayer extends Component<SimplePlayerProps> {
  constructor(props: SimplePlayerProps) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <audio id="mytrack" controls>
          <source src="audio.mp3" />
        </audio>
        <nav>
          <div id="defaultBar">
            <div id="progressBar" />
          </div>
          <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="playButton" />
            <button type="button" id="muteButton" />
            <span id="currentTime">0:00</span>/
            <span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any Help would be really appreciated :)
Many Thanks

Best Regards,
Musayyab Naveed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. The `play` method exists on `HTMLAudioElement` and not `HTMLElement`. `getElementById` returns `HTMLElement | null`, so you'd have to cast `mytrack` as `HTMLAudioElement` for TypeScript to allow it.

But that's not the main problem.

2. The real issue is that your code to get and play the audio file is running before the code (in `render`) that creates the audio element. If you're wanting to play the audio file immediately, try including the `autoplay` property on the `audio` element.

Comment: ohh, okay understand. No I don't just want to play the player immediately, I want to program it completely myself, so how should I call my functions?

Comment: Since you included the `controls` prop on the `audio` element, the user will have the ability to play/pause the audio. If you want further control, you could attach a `ref` to your `audio` element, and use that to control the audio. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748063/react-refs-audio-playback-unhandled-rejection-notsupportederror-on-ios)

Comment: `controls` prop is just temporary for testing purposes

Comment: can you maybe show an example of how I can cast it properly it Typescript?

Comment: Again, this won't solve your problem, but to cast it, you could do this ```const mytrack = document.getElementById('mytrack');
(mytrack as HTMLAudioElement).play();```

I would recommend using the `ref` approach.

Comment: Thank you it is working, I am just calling it from `componentDidMount()` so that it gets rendered before

Answer (score -1):

```
//file for export
export const AudioPlay = (file) => {
  new Audio(`/static/sounds/${file}`).play();    //under folder public
};

//file import
import {AudioPlay} from './comm';

//onClick event 
AudioPlay('stockin-ok.mp3');
```